# Exporting data in testcomplete8

Tags: testcomplete

Can i export data to some file from the tests (of the testcomplete 8) using some automatication or templates; Except using logs is there a way or smth?

Comment: You'll likely have better luck asking this on the [TestComplete forums](http://smartbear.com/forums/).

Comment: What data do you need to export (logs, scripts, something else...)? In what format do you need the output to be? Clarify the task - this may help you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague, I can only recommend using the following command:

```
    Log["SaveResultsAs"] ("Folder\\File.mht", 2);
```

This will create a single MHT files with a combined result of a test run.